# SKSpriteNode doesn't maintain current position after moveToParent function

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

The `SKNode` method `moveToParent` does not maintain its absolute position after moving to a new parent in the same scene. The node moves to another position.

The documentation for `moveToParent` says

> Moves the node to a new parent node in the scene. The node maintains its current position in scene coordinates.

Did I miss something?

update_01:

I realize something new for me. 
The moving node maintains its position only if its initial position is zero points.If it has a initial position, after moveToParent function, it moves, which makes me confuse as compared to apple documentation.

As I understand from "maintain", it does not move on the screen, just its position values are changed.

and please do not consider scene!.scaleMode, because it was tested without this(and ofcourse proper anchorPoint) and nothing changed.

This is my code and screenshots:

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

```
var counter:Int = 0

var touchTracker : [UITouch : SKNode] = [:]

  let yellowParentNode = SKSpriteNode()
  let blueParentNode = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
   scene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill


    let yellowPosition = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    let bluePosition = CGPointMake(200[![enter image description here][1]][1], 100)



    //yellow parent

    yellowParentNode.name = "yellow"
    yellowParentNode.color = UIColor.yellowColor()
    yellowParentNode.size.height = 50
    yellowParentNode.size.width = 50
    yellowParentNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)
    yellowParentNode.position  = yellowPosition
    self.addChild(yellowParentNode)

    //blue parent 

    blueParentNode.name = "blue"
    blueParentNode.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    blueParentNode.size.height = 50
    blueParentNode.size.width = 50
    blueParentNode.position = bluePosition
    blueParentNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)
    self.addChild(blueParentNode)

    //child
    let childNode = SKSpriteNode()
    childNode.color = UIColor.redColor()
    childNode.size.width = 20
    childNode.size.height = 20
    childNode.name = "child"
    childNode.position = CGPointMake(40, 40)
    childNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)

    yellowParentNode.addChild(childNode)

}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */


    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    touchTracker[touch as UITouch] = touchedNode


    if touchedNode.name == "child"
    {

    yellowParentNode.childNodeWithName("child")!.moveToParent(blueParentNode)

    }
```

}

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)


    let touchedNode = touchTracker[touch as UITouch]

    touchedNode?.position  = touchLocation

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
 //   let touch = touches.first as UITouch!



    touchTracker.removeAll()


}




override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */





}
```

}

this is the initial screen:

[image]

and this is next screen,which is after touching the child node:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a misunderstanding in the interpretation of the information provided by Apple. In fact "***moves the node to a new parent node***" it could understand that your node is already a child of a node in the same scene.

If you make for example:

```
let pos1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
let pos2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)/2,CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/2)

// make a big yellow node
let bigNode1 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(400,400))
addChild(bigNode1)
bigNode1.position = pos1

// make a big blue node
let bigNode2 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(400,400))
addChild(bigNode2)
bigNode2.position = pos2

// make a little red node as a child of bigNode1
let littleNode = SKSpriteNode.init(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100,100))
bigNode1.addChild(littleNode)
littleNode.position = CGPointZero
```

after you have this output:

[image]

Now if you do :

```
littleNode.moveToParent(bigNode2)
```

the output not change, exactly as explained by Apple.

**Update** (after 0x141E comment):

@0x141E As you can see, the position remain always 10,10 so it's correct:

[image]

Comment: Try setting the position of `littleNode` to `(10,10)` instead of `(0,0)` and run your test again.

Comment: @0x141E I've update my answer for you (P.S. actually these tests are maked with Xcode 7.3 and the latest stable swift version 2.2)

Comment: yes you are right. I was trying to move a childNode of sceneNode(meaning immediate parent is sceneNode) to another childNode of sceneNode,which causes problematic position. thanks for your descriptive answer. and  UP UP UP :-)

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano - I have updated my question. Any ideas ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dogan Ok I've seen, I will try to give you an update to my answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You may be misinformed here, and Alessandro's answer does not explain why things are happening.

The position property is always relative to the parent.  This is not what scene coordinates are.  If you want to get the scene coordinates,  you need to convert the position to the scene.

Now when you use moveToParent, you obviously are moving the node's parent property to the new parent.  This means that the nodes position has to change, since the parent is changing.  Now the node position has to change in order to adjust for the new parent, so that is still stays on the same spot on the scene.

E.G.

Node 1 lies on 10, 10 to the scene,  Node 2 lies on 20,10 to the scene.

Node A is a child of node 1, and is positioned at 0,0 (scene coordinate (10,10))

We then move Node A from node 1 to node 2.

If position never changes (stays at (0,0)), this means that when viewed on screen, the scene coordinate would be 20,10, which is wrong

The position would have to change to (-10,0)  because you take the parent (20,10) and need to adjust it by (-10,0) to get the scene coordinate of Node A back to (10,10)

Comment: You wrong when you say : "Now when you use moveToParent, you obviously are moving the parent." you don't move the parent, you move the node to another parent.

Comment: I meant the parent property, ill reword it

Comment: Apples documentation clearly states "The node maintains its current position in scene coordinates." Does this not imply that the node's position property will change so that in its new parent"s coordinate system, its position on screen remains unchanged?

Comment: Yes, This is why OP got confused,  he thought position was scene coordinates